# forward Traffic (like proxy) and keep source ip

Tags: networking, iptables

I would like to point the connection to my A server 25565 port to another 30000 port of B server. But I need to access the ip address of the user who sent me a connection request from B server.
I have no idea how to do it. I've directed the traffic using the proxy logic in Java, but the performance is bad.
Is there another alternative way I can use it?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-destination myAnotherServerIP:30000
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

I did by adding this iptables rules. But I can't reach the IP address where the request came from. (Source IP Adress)

I don't have to do it that iptables rules. Any alternative would be a useful system or path.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to achieve that. For example:

- [HA-proxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)
- [nginx TCP proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/)

Both are build for high throughput and low latency and both can be configure to provide decent access information.